# Get time duration per each available day

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get users visits duration for each day in MySQL.
I have table like:

```
user_id,date,time_start, time_end
1, 2018-09-01, 09:00:00, 12:30:00
2, 2018-09-01, 13:00:00, 15:10:00
1, 2018-09-03, 09:30:00, 12:30:00
2, 2018-09-03, 13:00:00, 15:10:00
```

and need to get:

```
user_id,2018-09-01_duration,2018-09-03_duration
1,03:30:00,03:00:00
2,02:10:00,02:10:00
```

So columns need to be dynamic as some dates can be missed (2018-09-02).
Is it possible to do with one query without explicit joins per each day (as some days can be null)?

**Update #1**

Yes, I can generate columns in application side, But I still have terrible query like

```
SELECT user_id, d1.dt AS "2018-08-01_duration", d2.dt AS "2018-08-03_duration"...
FROM (SELECT 
            user_id,
            time_format(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in),time_norm),"%H:%i") AS dt 
        FROM visits 
        WHERE date = "2018-09-01") d1
        LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
            user_id,
            time_format(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in),time_norm),"%H:%i") AS dt 
        FROM visits 
        WHERE date = "2018-09-03") d3 
        ON users.id = d3.user_id...
```

**Update #2**

Yes, data like

```
select user_id, date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total
from visits
group by user_id, date;
```

is correct, but in this case data for users goes consistently. And I hope there's the way when I have rows with users and columns with dates (like in example above)

Comment: How about grouping by `user, day`? And most probably, if you  are thinking about dynamic columns, you are thinking it wrong.

Comment: Also, store datetime as a single entity

Comment: Use your application code to create dynamic columns (for display purposes etc). Dont use sql to create dynamic columns

Comment: @NiVeR yes, in theary griuping is required for this case, but how exactly... As grouping use rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select user_id, date, sum(time_end - time_start) 
from table
group by user_id, date;
```

You will need to do some tweaking, as you didn't mention the RDBMS provider, but it should give you a clear idea on how to do it.

Comment: I've already have "mysql" tag :) Anyway added in text too.

Yes, I can use something like 

`select user_id, date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total
from visits
group by user_id, date;`

but it's not convinient format - I want (or at least try) to get table when rows are users and columns are dates...

Comment: I already mentioned in the comment that this is not correct in my opinion. I don't see why this is not a good format.

Comment: This format is.. I don't know, "single-entry-based" maybe. I mean that we have just one entry after another. But I hope that it is possible to create query to get "table-based" result - like if we need to export it to excel with one row per user and one column per day.

Yes, it can be done in application-side, but as for me it would be better to have "Excel" format from sql query

Answer (score 1):

There's no dynamic way to use pivotting in MySQL but you might [use the following](http://rextester.com/CFX9557) for your case :

```
create table t(user_id int, time_start timestamp, time_end timestamp);
insert into t values(1,'2018-09-01 09:00:00', '2018-09-01 12:30:00');
insert into t values(2,'2018-09-01 13:00:00', '2018-09-01 15:10:00');
insert into t values(1,'2018-09-03 09:30:00', '2018-09-03 12:30:00');
insert into t values(2,'2018-09-03 13:00:00', '2018-09-03 15:10:00');

select min(q.user_id) as user_id, 
       min(CASE WHEN (q.date='2018-09-01') THEN q.time_diff END) as '2018-09-01_duration',
       min(CASE WHEN (q.date='2018-09-03') THEN q.time_diff END) as '2018-09-03_duration'
  from
  (
   select user_id, date(time_start) date,
          concat(concat(lpad(hour(timediff(time_start, time_end)),2,'0'),':'),
          concat(lpad(minute(timediff(time_start, time_end)),2,'0'),':'),
          lpad(second(timediff(time_start, time_end)),2,'0')) as time_diff      
     from t
  ) q
  group by user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, as far as I understand performance will be better than for joins but in this query we will have ~30 "CASE" statements.I still hope it can be prettyfied, but with each answer I lost this hope :(

Answer (score 0):

By the query you can solve your problem. the query is dynamic and you can improve it.
i use TSQL for the query, you can use the idea in MySQL.

```
declare
    @columns    as nvarchar(max),
    @query      as nvarchar(max)

select
    @columns    =
    stuff
    ((
            select
            distinct
                ',' + quotename([date]) 
            from
                table_test
            for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

--select    @columns

set @query =
'with
    cte_result
as
(
    select
        [user_id]   ,
        [date]      ,
        time_start  ,
        time_end    ,
        datediff(minute, time_start, time_end)  as duration
    from
        table_test
)
select
    [user_id], ' + @columns + '
from 
(
    select
        [user_id]   ,
        [date]      ,
        duration
    from
        cte_result
)
    sourceTable
pivot 
(
    sum(duration)
    for [date] in (' + @columns + ')
)
    pivotTable'


execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dates that you want in the result set, you don't need a dynamic query.  You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-09-01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(time_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total_20180901,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-09-02' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(time_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total_20180902,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-09-03' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(time_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total_20180903
from visits
group by user_id;
```

You only need dynamic SQL if you don't know the dates you want in the result set.  In that case, I would suggest following the same structure with the dates that you do want.